# Is there a modular multiplier design that can give the result in 1 cycle?

Tags: vlsi, multiplication

I need to perform modular multiplication on two large numbers (more than 10,000 bits wide). I've found papers that give designs that can that calculate the result in N cycles, but in my case, that would take over 10,000 cycles to compute. How can it be done without iterating, preferably in a single cycle?

Comment: Is the requirement for a single cycle because you want it to be fast, or because you want it to be simpler without iterations? You could probably make a gigantic and extremely slow combinational multiplier that doesn't need a clock.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the application? A 10,000 bit number is huge. Are all of the digits in the answer significant or can you do an approximation?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can do is the [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) which runs in \$O(n \log n \log \log n)\$ time and can be implemented in an FPGA: [FPGA Based Schonhage Strassen Integer Multiplication Algorithm](https://www.jardcs.org/backissues/abstract.php?archiveid=3461)